# Create an institute-like macro for beamer

Tags: beamer, macros

I would like to create a new `command`/`macro` with the same functionalities `\institute` has in `beamer` (`\shortinstitute`, `\insertinstitute`, `\insertshortinstitute`).
I search on this site has showed to me that the `macro` for `\author` (which, as far as I can see, has the same functionalities) is defined in `LaTeX` as

```
def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}}
\def\@author{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\author given}\@ehc}
```

which, I am pretty sure, is not the one `beamer` uses. I have also checked the definitions provided in the `amsart.cls` file, but it is beyond my knowledge.

Is there any elegant way, one which, because the way is defined, has all the commands `\shortfoo`, `\insertfoo`, `\insertshortfoo` , etc., automatically established by `LaTeX`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{\@dblarg\beamer@foo}
\long\def\beamer@foo[#1]#2{%
  \def\insertfoo{#2}%
  \def\insertshortfoo{#1}%
  }
\foo{}
\makeatother


\foo[short foo]{long foo}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
  
  \insertfoo
  
  \insertshortfoo
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: What is the benefit of using `\@dblarg\beamer@` over "just" using a non-beamer specific `\newcommand`? Maybe my question is naive :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The "advantage" is that like this one can simply copy the beamer code and only has to change the name :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner ... but more seriously, this way one does not have to worry about the different cases for when the short title is specified or not.